# Specify multiple generic types for implementation

Tags: c#, generics, castle-windsor

Given the following service structure:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Print();
}

public class Foo<T> : IFoo
{
    private T _item;

    public Foo(T item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_item);
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to register the `Foo<T>` component with multiple types, other than by explicitly enumerating them? This works but I thought there may be a better way:

```
foreach (var t in myTypes)
{
    container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>()
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(Foo<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { t })));
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with this code? What kind of improvement do you want?

Comment: I had thought maybe there would be an equivalent to `IGenericServiceStrategy` or `IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy` that I had not found

Comment: For when you know all the types upfront, this code is fine and your container ends up with a separate component for each `t` which is more explicit. @samy's implementation would be advisable in case where you want a single component and you don't know all the `t`s upfront at registration time or simply prefer to be more dynamic. Both are fine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in the `foreach type` loop is reducing the number of open generic components down to the same number as `IFoo`; there is a way to wrap this in a clean implementation by using the [Castle `IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy` interface](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy.ashx) but this interface only lets you close a generic type with one signature; you cannot close the generic type with mutiple types.

```
public class YourCustomGenericCloser: IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy
{
   public Type[] GetGenericArguments(ComponentModel model, CreationContext context)
   {
      if(context.RequestedType == typeof(IFoo))
      {
         return typeof(TheDefaultTypeToCloseAgainst);
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

I think that so far your method is perhaps the simpler way of registering concrete generic types against a basic interface.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured